# find a list of row position of last true value in each column

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following code:

```
ttmbond = 10
daywalk = np.arange(0,30)
dtm = ttmbond - daywalk/252 

curve_list = [0.083,0.25,0.5,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]

pos1= np.ones((len(daywalk+1),len(curve_list)))
pos2 = pos1*curve_list

pos3 = pos2 <= dtm
```

which now gives me this
[TRUE/FALSE ndarray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFVzT.png)
I would like to get a list of row index of last true value in each column. From this example, my final result should be something like [12, 11 , 11, 11, 11, 11, ....]

Or is there anyway to get the position of the value from the curve_list which is the highest smaller or equal to value of values in dtm?

Thanks

Comment: Define the values for the variables

Comment: As in my example, values in dtm are [10, 9.96, 9.92, ......]. By comparing dtm to curve_list, 10 (12th position from curve_list) is the highest smaller or equal to 10 in dtm. And 9 (11th position from curve_list) is the highest smaller value than 9.96, 9.92, .... from dtm.

Comment: What are `column_list` and `pos` in your code? I would be happy to help you with a little bit more of information

Comment: I'm sorry for my typo. I edited the question. column_list is curve_list and pos is pos1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending your code:

```
ttmbond = 10
daywalk = np.arange(0,30)
dtm = ttmbond - daywalk/252 

curve_list = [0.083,0.25,0.5,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]

pos1= np.ones((len(daywalk+1),len(curve_list)))
pos2 = pos1*curve_list

pos3 = (pos2 <= (dtm+pos1.T).T)

temp = np.where(pos3==True)
loc = np.where((temp[0][1:]-temp[0][:-1])==1)[0]
res = np.append(temp[1][loc], temp[1][-1])
print(res)

'''
Output:
[13 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12
 12 12 12 12 12 12]
'''
```

Other way around:

```
ttmbond = 10
daywalk = np.arange(0,30)
dtm = ttmbond - daywalk/252 

curve_list = [0.083,0.25,0.5,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]

res = [np.where((i>0)==True)[0][0] for i in [curve_list - i for i in dtm]]
print(res)

'''
Output:
[13, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12]
'''
```